# Howto repair dead-pixels automatically?

Tags: dead-pixel

My camera has some dead-pixels. The images are in JPG format. Only on some images (but still more than 300 images) they turn completely red on dark background. I want to automatically determine pixels that have a high difference to its neighbourhood, and then replace them by interpolation of the neighborhood. I would argue this has already been done? What do you use to recover dead-pixels in your holiday photographs?

Answer (score 3):

You could try working with ImageMagick, or even write your own JPG analyzer code, but I doubt you can find a sure algorithm to do this. What about the eyes - they'd be relatively more bright than the ajdacent pixels .. and more examples come to mind. The best you could hope for would be a pre-selection, showing you a zoomed-in area of a *possible candidate*, then giving you the option to work on it or not. 
I've also heard that dead pixels are able to identify cameras, because they're always at the same coordinates, but this is hearsay (for me). If that is the case for you then there'd be lots of ways .. it would depend on your operating system, graphics tools. Like using imagemagick or scripting in your gui application of choice.